# Multi-Column not working in IE11 Using ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net, master-pages, internet-explorer-11, multiple-columns

I have searched and searched and am at my wits end with this problem.

I'm using VS2008, ASP.net 2.0.

I'm trying to use multiple columns, and it works fine in Firefox & Chrome, but am having problems in IE11.  I've read all the documentation that says it works, and it does with a plain .aspx & .html file, but when using it from within a master page, it simply does not work.  When I view developer tools in IE 11 on the page using the master page, none of the multi-column attributes (column-count, column-rule, column-gap) seem to be accepted (red, squiggly line underneath them).  My bare-bones .aspx file, however, everything works as expected.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!  Any suggested work-arounds?

Thanks!!

Here's my plain test .aspx file which works with no problem:

```html
<%@ Page Language="Oxygene" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ColumnTestForIE.aspx.pas" Inherits="ColumnTestForIE" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .testTwoColumns 
        {
            column-count: 2 !important;
            column-gap: 1px !important;
         columns: 2 !important;
            -moz-column-count: 2 !important;
            -moz-column-gap: 1px !important;
            -ms-column-count: 2 !important;
            -ms-column-gap: 1px !important;
            -webkit-column-count: 2 !important;
            -webkit-column-gap: 1px !important;
            -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000 !important;
            -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000 !important;   
            column-rule: 1px solid #000 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="testTwoColumns">
        <p style="overflow: hidden;">ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in sodales sapien. Quisque id quam lacinia nisl consectetur finibus. Aliquam vestibulum urna quis cursus congue. Nam risus odio, pulvinar et sagittis quis, imperdiet quis erat. Quisque lobortis est neque, sed congue neque iaculis porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et arcu nisi. Proin vitae aliquam elit, eu lobortis massa. Morbi risus enim, malesuada nec placerat bibendum, gravida eu eros. </p>
        <p style="overflow: hidden;">Nullam accumsan turpis at eros condimentum varius. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam nec metus convallis, dapibus sem eu, rutrum sem. Etiam elementum, odio mattis lacinia tristique, ante dolor facilisis ipsum, ut volutpat tortor ante non augue. Maecenas placerat enim sollicitudin tellus aliquet, id varius elit fermentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam dignissim pretium risus eget tincidunt. Vestibulum eu mauris nec nisl accumsan ornare sed nec turpis. In turpis metus, ultricies ac ultricies a, porttitor vulputate nisl. Etiam laoreet accumsan turpis, ac semper justo feugiat nec. </p>
        <p style="overflow: hidden;">Suspendisse eget molestie tortor, id efficitur purus. Sed vitae eros libero. Maecenas convallis tellus non odio ornare, pulvinar finibus neque aliquet. Nulla lorem quam, congue non felis non, faucibus dapibus ex. Vivamus egestas quis arcu sed pretium. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed fringilla mattis dolor, non ullamcorper neque accumsan id. Nunc blandit purus eget maximus suscipit. Nullam ac commodo tellus, at dictum libero. Aenean et tortor id velit vehicula eleifend. Nullam at dolor euismod, mollis justo in, eleifend orci. Quisque facilisis mi vel massa porta semper vitae nec magna. Ut bibendum, lectus ac vestibulum tempor, odio turpis faucibus elit, non imperdiet dui turpis vel ipsum. Duis lectus magna, dapibus vitae justo aliquam, cursus molestie ante. </p>
        <p style="overflow: hidden;">Mauris molestie commodo augue. Sed ultrices sit amet arcu a malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices leo nec mi malesuada gravida. Vivamus feugiat fermentum mauris at gravida. Nam iaculis, ipsum et malesuada iaculis, est orci interdum tortor, imperdiet elementum odio velit placerat sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus laoreet laoreet sodales. Phasellus pharetra condimentum quam. Donec fringilla leo dui, et porta odio eleifend a. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla porta est sed cursus fermentum. Praesent scelerisque orci sit amet justo efficitur dictum.</p>
        <p style="overflow: hidden;">Donec vitae diam gravida purus volutpat auctor. Proin id mollis arcu. Mauris fermentum malesuada ante, ac rutrum mauris molestie ut. Sed consequat neque condimentum turpis tristique sodales. Maecenas sed ex non tellus fermentum varius sed id est. Etiam tempor nibh neque. Sed ac sem et sem lacinia egestas in vel arcu. </p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I try these two files, both a master page and a web-form that uses it:

MasterPage:

```html
<%@ Master Language="Oxygene" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ColumnTestMP.master.pas" Inherits="ColumnTestMP" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
       <style type='text/css'>
        .testTwoColumns 
        {
            column-count: 2 !important;
            column-gap: 1px !important;
         columns: 2 !important;
            -moz-column-count: 2 !important;
            -moz-column-gap: 1px !important;
            -ms-column-count: 2 !important;
            -ms-column-gap: 1px !important;
            -webkit-column-count: 2 !important;
            -webkit-column-gap: 1px !important;
            -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000 !important;
            -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000 !important;   
            column-rule: 1px solid #000 !important;
            
        }
        </style>
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:contentplaceholder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    
        <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:contentplaceholder>
    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Web form that uses it:

```html
<%@ Page Language="Oxygene" MasterPageFile="~/ColumnTestMP.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ColumnTestMasterPageForIE.aspx.pas" Inherits="ColumnTestMasterPageForIE" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div class="testTwoColumns">
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in sodales sapien. Quisque id quam lacinia nisl consectetur finibus. Aliquam vestibulum urna quis cursus congue. Nam risus odio, pulvinar et sagittis quis, imperdiet quis erat. Quisque lobortis est neque, sed congue neque iaculis porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et arcu nisi. Proin vitae aliquam elit, eu lobortis massa. Morbi risus enim, malesuada nec placerat bibendum, gravida eu eros. </p>
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">Nullam accumsan turpis at eros condimentum varius. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam nec metus convallis, dapibus sem eu, rutrum sem. Etiam elementum, odio mattis lacinia tristique, ante dolor facilisis ipsum, ut volutpat tortor ante non augue. Maecenas placerat enim sollicitudin tellus aliquet, id varius elit fermentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam dignissim pretium risus eget tincidunt. Vestibulum eu mauris nec nisl accumsan ornare sed nec turpis. In turpis metus, ultricies ac ultricies a, porttitor vulputate nisl. Etiam laoreet accumsan turpis, ac semper justo feugiat nec. </p>
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">Suspendisse eget molestie tortor, id efficitur purus. Sed vitae eros libero. Maecenas convallis tellus non odio ornare, pulvinar finibus neque aliquet. Nulla lorem quam, congue non felis non, faucibus dapibus ex. Vivamus egestas quis arcu sed pretium. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed fringilla mattis dolor, non ullamcorper neque accumsan id. Nunc blandit purus eget maximus suscipit. Nullam ac commodo tellus, at dictum libero. Aenean et tortor id velit vehicula eleifend. Nullam at dolor euismod, mollis justo in, eleifend orci. Quisque facilisis mi vel massa porta semper vitae nec magna. Ut bibendum, lectus ac vestibulum tempor, odio turpis faucibus elit, non imperdiet dui turpis vel ipsum. Duis lectus magna, dapibus vitae justo aliquam, cursus molestie ante. </p>
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">Mauris molestie commodo augue. Sed ultrices sit amet arcu a malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices leo nec mi malesuada gravida. Vivamus feugiat fermentum mauris at gravida. Nam iaculis, ipsum et malesuada iaculis, est orci interdum tortor, imperdiet elementum odio velit placerat sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus laoreet laoreet sodales. Phasellus pharetra condimentum quam. Donec fringilla leo dui, et porta odio eleifend a. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla porta est sed cursus fermentum. Praesent scelerisque orci sit amet justo efficitur dictum.</p>
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">Donec vitae diam gravida purus volutpat auctor. Proin id mollis arcu. Mauris fermentum malesuada ante, ac rutrum mauris molestie ut. Sed consequat neque condimentum turpis tristique sodales. Maecenas sed ex non tellus fermentum varius sed id est. Etiam tempor nibh neque. Sed ac sem et sem lacinia egestas in vel arcu. </p>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

The code-behind that is rendered is exactly the same both without the masterpage and with, so I don't understand why one version renders the colums as expected, and one doesn't.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding "overflow: hidden;" to the divs.

Comment: Thanks Adam!  This seemed to work for this simple example.  In a more complicated application, this did not work - nothing seemed to work, so I ended up giving up and doing what I needed with relatively positioned divs.  Lots of hours wasted, and in the end the project just needed to be done!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the CSS from the main files.

Download system files only works on a TCP.

Your code looks fine otherwise, but make sure you don't get carried away with the DIVs, because they'll start lining up instrumentally, rather than physically.

Like this:

REMOVE DASHL